# I am getting error in summarize function for bar chart visualization through ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, summarize, mutate

[code chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81V7p.jpg) Here is the code chunk I am running on R studio and it gives me error  (Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and
`group_by()`.)
What is the correct code chunk to obtain bar chart for attrition dataset

I tried coomas after sum and group by but it also gives error and wrongs the code syntax

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can include your code as text, and it also helps if you can share some example of data that demonstrates the issue. Do you get the same error if you just run the first line through `mutate(countT = sum(N))`?